# How to creat key and list of elements from column as values from dataframes

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary

How to create python dictionary using the data below
Df1:

| Id | mail-id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz@gm |
| 1 | ygzbb |
| 2. | Ghh. |
| 2. | Hjkk. |

I want it as

```
{1:[xyz@gm,ygzbb], 2:[Ghh,Hjkk]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
data = [
    [1, "xyz@gm"],
    [1, "ygzbb"],
    [2, "Ghh"],
    [2, "Hjkk"],
]

dataDict = {}

for k, v in data:
    if k not in dataDict:
        dataDict[k] = []
    dataDict[k].append(v)

print(dataDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `groupby` the `Id` column and turn the `mail-id` into a list in a dictionary comprehension:

```py
{k:v["mail-id"].values.tolist() for k,v in df.groupby("Id")}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to iterate over the `set` version of the ids and check one by one:

```
>>> _d = {}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[1,1,2,2],"mail-id":["xyz@gm","ygzbb","Ghh","Hjkk"]})
>>> for x in set(df["Id"]):
...     _d.update({x:df[df["id"]==x]["mail_id"]})
```

But it's much faster to use dictionary comprehension and builtin pandas [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html); a quick look from the [Official Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs):

> A groupby operation involves some combination of splitting the object, applying a function, and combining the results. This can be used to group large amounts of data and compute operations on these groups.

```
DataFrame.groupby(by=None, axis=0, level=None, as_index=True, sort=True, group_keys=True, squeeze=NoDefault.no_default, observed=False, dropna=True)
```

as [@fsimonjetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15873043/fsimonjetz) pointed out, this code will be sufficent:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Id":[1,1,2,2],"mail-id":["xyz@gm","ygzbb","Ghh","Hjkk"]})
>>> {k:v["mail-id"].values.tolist() for k,v in df.groupby("Id")}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df.groupby('Id').agg(list).to_dict()['mail-id']
```

Output:

```
{1: ['xyz@gm', 'ygzbb'], 2: ['Ghh.', 'Hjkk.']}
```